# Отчеты в java

Tags: java

Необходимо создать отчет (желательно с диаграммой) в Java программе. Как, что, на чем? Если есть инструкция или урок, то было-бы вообще хорошо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports)

Comment: jasper лучший, тем более, если надо графики, но для небольший программ можно и jLog и обычную запись в файл =)

Comment: имхо он не то чтобы лучше, он вообще единственный относительно адекватный движок для отчетов в Java-мире (чтоб с таблицами, графиками, кросстабами, вложенными отчетами, гибкой версткой). Но до дельфийско-дотнетного FastReport все равно не дотягивает, да и багами не прекращает радовать из года в год.